# How do I use a matrix/dataframe to multiply a dataframe into long format?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a large dataset into long format for analysis by multiplying a matrix-style dataframe to tell R how many duplicates of each row I want according the a specific column. I've used the gather function for something vaguely similar but it's not quite similar enough that I can work out how to alter it.

My dataset looks like this:

```
SPECTRA     AV         GROUP    MS
1A1TOP0001  25.07660289 1   
1A1TOP0003  65.39676867 1   
1A1TOP0005  19.10770948 1   
1A2TOP0002  25.00892869 1   
1A2TOP0004  20.65255779 1   
1A3TOP0001  26.44492725 2   
1A3TOP0003  41.67009905 2   
1A3TOP0005  18.6924627  2   
1B1TOP0001  14.18131153 3   
1B1TOP0002  20.62052297 3   
1B1TOP0004  23.84429213 3   
1B2TOP0001  34.37076111 3   
1B2TOP0002  18.79169997 3   
1B2TOP0003  15.94607426 3   
1B2TOP0004  10.70171397 3
```

What I want is to have each row duplicated according to GROUP. For example, if I have this dataset/matrix:

```
GROUP   SM  PM  SF  PF
1       2   1   0   0
2       0   1   0   4
3       3   1   1   0
```

I need the MS column to be represented by one of SM, PM, SF or PF, and the number of times it is duplicated is the value for that group. So the output should be this:

```
SPECTRA     AV        GROUP MS
1A1TOP0001  25.07660289 1   SM
1A1TOP0001  25.07660289 1   SM
1A1TOP0001  25.07660289 1   PM
1A1TOP0003  65.39676867 1   SM
1A1TOP0003  65.39676867 1   SM
1A1TOP0003  65.39676867 1   PM
1A1TOP0005  19.10770948 1   SM
1A1TOP0005  19.10770948 1   SM
1A1TOP0005  19.10770948 1   PM
1A2TOP0002  25.00892869 1   SM
1A2TOP0002  25.00892869 1   SM
1A2TOP0002  25.00892869 1   PM
1A2TOP0004  20.65255779 1   SM
1A2TOP0004  20.65255779 1   SM
1A2TOP0004  20.65255779 1   PM
1A3TOP0001  26.44492725 2   PM
1A3TOP0001  26.44492725 2   PF
1A3TOP0001  26.44492725 2   PF
1A3TOP0001  26.44492725 2   PF
1A3TOP0001  26.44492725 2   PF
1A3TOP0003  41.67009905 2   PM
1A3TOP0003  41.67009905 2   PF
1A3TOP0003  41.67009905 2   PF
1A3TOP0003  41.67009905 2   PF
1A3TOP0003  41.67009905 2   PF
1A3TOP0005  18.6924627  2   PM
1A3TOP0005  18.6924627  2   PF
1A3TOP0005  18.6924627  2   PF
1A3TOP0005  18.6924627  2   PF
1A3TOP0005  18.6924627  2   PF
```

I hope that makes sense. I'm not the best at this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way that I think works. It converts your multiplying matrix into a dataframe with `gather`, duplicates the rows based on the number of rows a given MS name should have for the given group, then joins the duplicated rows back to the SPECTRA dataset. Libraries used are `tidyr`, `plyr`, and `dplyr`.

Convert multiplying dataframe to a two-column dataframe:

```
mult %<>% 
  gather(key = MS, value = rep, - GROUP) %>%
  arrange(GROUP)
```

Duplicate the rows and drop the no-longer-needed `rep` column:

```
dup_rows <- subset(ddply(mult, c("GROUP", "MS"), function(x) {
  x[rep(1:nrow(x), each = x$rep),]
}), select = c(GROUP, MS))
```

Join the multi-row dataframe back to the original- rows are duplicated as necessary. The `arrange` is not necessary but I think gets back to the order you have in your example output.

```
output <- left_join(df, dup_rows) %>% 
  arrange(GROUP, SPECTRA, desc(MS))

> output
      SPECTRA       AV GROUP MS
1  1A1TOP0001 25.07660     1 SM
2  1A1TOP0001 25.07660     1 SM
3  1A1TOP0001 25.07660     1 PM
4  1A1TOP0003 65.39677     1 SM
5  1A1TOP0003 65.39677     1 SM
6  1A1TOP0003 65.39677     1 PM
7  1A1TOP0005 19.10771     1 SM
8  1A1TOP0005 19.10771     1 SM
9  1A1TOP0005 19.10771     1 PM
10 1A2TOP0002 25.00893     1 SM
11 1A2TOP0002 25.00893     1 SM
12 1A2TOP0002 25.00893     1 PM
13 1A2TOP0004 20.65256     1 SM
14 1A2TOP0004 20.65256     1 SM
15 1A2TOP0004 20.65256     1 PM
16 1A3TOP0001 26.44493     2 PM
17 1A3TOP0001 26.44493     2 PF
18 1A3TOP0001 26.44493     2 PF
19 1A3TOP0001 26.44493     2 PF
20 1A3TOP0001 26.44493     2 PF
21 1A3TOP0003 41.67010     2 PM
22 1A3TOP0003 41.67010     2 PF
23 1A3TOP0003 41.67010     2 PF
24 1A3TOP0003 41.67010     2 PF
25 1A3TOP0003 41.67010     2 PF
26 1A3TOP0005 18.69246     2 PM
27 1A3TOP0005 18.69246     2 PF
28 1A3TOP0005 18.69246     2 PF
29 1A3TOP0005 18.69246     2 PF
30 1A3TOP0005 18.69246     2 PF
31 1B1TOP0001 14.18131     3 SM
32 1B1TOP0001 14.18131     3 SM
33 1B1TOP0001 14.18131     3 SM
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "SPECTRA     AV         GROUP
1A1TOP0001  25.07660289 1   
1A1TOP0003  65.39676867 1   
1A1TOP0005  19.10770948 1   
1A2TOP0002  25.00892869 1   
1A2TOP0004  20.65255779 1   
1A3TOP0001  26.44492725 2   
1A3TOP0003  41.67009905 2   
1A3TOP0005  18.6924627  2   
1B1TOP0001  14.18131153 3   
1B1TOP0002  20.62052297 3   
1B1TOP0004  23.84429213 3   
1B2TOP0001  34.37076111 3   
1B2TOP0002  18.79169997 3   
1B2TOP0003  15.94607426 3   
1B2TOP0004  10.70171397 3", header = TRUE, sep = "")

mult <- read.table(text = "GROUP   SM  PM  SF  PF
1       2   1   0   0
2       0   1   0   4
3       3   1   1   0", header = TRUE, sep = "")
```

Libraries:

```
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
```